# Session variables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

I am starting a session in controller but i am unable to call that session variable in view.
When i am working on localhost its working perfectly but on server there is nothing in that session variable. I am writting my code:=
Controller

```
              if($_REQUEST['username'] == $result['users'][$i]->username &&                              $_REQUEST['pass'] == $result['users'][$i]->password)
           {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] =  $result['users'][$i]->username;
        $_SESSION['profilename'] = $result['users'][$i]->profilename;
        die;
        $_SESSION['password'] =  $result['users'][$i]->password;
        $_SESSION['id'] =  $result['users'][$i]->ID;        
            echo $_SESSION['id'];
            die;         
        print_r($result['users']);
        $url=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
        redirect("$referal?user=profile");

        echo "<script>location.href='$referal?user=profile'</script>";


        return true;


        die;
    }
```

View :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_GET['action']!='logout'){  
                        ?>
                        <script>alert("hii");</script>
}
```

Comment: Use CodeIgniter's built in sessions instead: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: you need to know how to read the documentation Nitish

Comment: Can we use core php sessions in codeigniter??? Alexander

Comment: You should be able to. but then again you gotta use the session_start() too. But I think if you have it autoload you should be fine I think

Answer (score -1):

First use the built in SESSIOn library for codeigniter. But I had an issue where the session variable didn't get saved/read. Turned out to be a small issue with itself (some session fixation issue). https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session sorts it out for you

Comment: The Native session you are referring to is for very old versions of CodeIgniter.

Comment: hmmm. I had that issue with 2.1.3 so I had to use that from github. And thank you for the downvote for who ever did it